# set order confirmation email step

Tags: order-confirmation

When customer make an order.
I cannot received order confirmation trough email.

Customer also cannot received it.

Please advice on how to fix this issue.

Comment: issue on the demo server or live server?

Comment: Hi, You are more likely to get an answer after including some more details in the question, like what is in the logs, what things you have tried and didn't work, which server you are working on, is it localhost or a live server, what configuration you have in admin for mails etc.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the 1.9.x.x magento version, the order confirmation mail is sent by the Magento cron system.
Please be sure to have the cron setted up properly.

To make a quick check you can call the cron "manually" invoke the following link:

```
www.yourmagento/cron.php
```